# Keycloak Java Servlet Adapter example or code blocks

Tags: authentication, servlets, filter, adapter, keycloak

I want to use the Keycloak Authorization Services. I read documents about that. I'm working on the java servlet filter method. Do you have any example project about that? Or anythink about java side for adapter

My Codes:
KeycloakFilter.java

```
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import org.keycloak.adapters.servlet.KeycloakOIDCFilter;
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Component;
import org.osgi.service.http.whiteboard.HttpWhiteboardConstants;

@Component(
    immediate = true,
    service = Filter.class,
    property = {
        KeycloakOIDCFilter.CONFIG_FILE_PARAM + "=" + "keycloak.json",
        HttpWhiteboardConstants.HTTP_WHITEBOARD_FILTER_PATTERN + "=" +"/*",
        HttpWhiteboardConstants.HTTP_WHITEBOARD_CONTEXT_SELECT + "=" + "(osgi.http.whiteboard.context.name=keycloak)"
    }
)


public class KeycloakFilter extends KeycloakOIDCFilter {
  //
}
```

web.xml

```
 <filter>
        <filter-name>Keycloak Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.keycloak.adapters.servlet.KeycloakOIDCFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>Keycloak Filter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/test.jsp</url-pattern>

</filter-mapping>
```

KeycloakFilter.cfg

```
keycloak.config.file = keycloak.json
osgi.http.whiteboard.filter.pattern = /*
```

[image: Netbeans Project Treeview]

At this scenario, after keycloak login given me an error like "HTTP Status 403 - Forbidden"